# Searching Google for files and pages which contain .something

Tags: google-search

I am doing some security research, and am wanting to search Google for hidden files that have been accidentally included in websites.

These hidden Unix files are all ".filename" and ".foldername/files"

Can someone show me how to search for paths that contain "."?

For example, `inurl:.svn` doesn't seem to look for the period but just the "svn"

Comment: You can use `filetype:*` to search for files with a certain extension, but in this case it seems to return just URLs that contain '.svn'

Answer (score 4):

Filetype searches only work for specific types on Google.

Have a look at the "Advanced Search" for details.

Otherwise, you need to put the query in quotes to try and stop Google from being too clever! This *will* of course return more than you want as it searches for the text as well as the URL.

You are right that `inurl` and `filetype` ignore the period. A quoted search term though will take it into account.

Comment: This is great, however using "url:'.svn'" yields nothing...?